# form not submitting which was loaded via load function

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a html page (partialpage.html) having form via load function, but after this form is loaded in the main page, form is not getting submitted. The jquery code of the loaded form is in the main page.

**Partial partialpage.html:**

```
 <div id="askcon">
    <table align="center" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0" class="tb1">

    <form name="f1" id="f1" >
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="box5"/></td>

    <td><input type="text"  name="fname"  id="box5"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" id="box7" class="sub" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </div>
```

**Jquery in Main Page where this partialpage.html is loaded:**

```
<script>
 $("#f1").on("submit", function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();               
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'post.php',
         data: $(this).serialize(),       
         dataType: 'json',
         error : function(){ alert("error");}
   }).done(function(data) {
        if ('url' in data) {
            $("#askcon").load("form.htm", function () {
                $('#resfname').html(data.fname);       
                $('#resurl').html(data.url);

            });
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: dont't think that load("form.htm", function....) can work, as load() is similar or identical to on('load',function...) which can not handle parameters. May be you want load the form.htm into the div#askcon, you'll need to trigger another ajax request.

Comment: Same problem here. Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you queued your function with .done to .on("submit",...) instead of success: function to the ajax request, if I get it right. Nevertheless, you have to go into the .load() issue, as I mentioned above. I didn't correct this part of your code.

```
$("#f1").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();               
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),       
            dataType: 'json',
            error : function(){ alert("error");},
            success: function(data) {
                if ('url' in data) {
                    $("#askcon").load("form.htm", function () {
                        $('#resfname').html(data.fname);       
                        $('#resurl').html(data.url);
                    });
                }
        });
});
```